# Why this aquire/release ordering example can fire?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is a example from "C++ Concurrency in Action", list 5.7

```
std::atomic<bool> x,y;
std::atomic<int> z;    

void write_x()
{
    x.store(true,std::memory_order_release);
}

void write_y()
{
    y.store(true,std::memory_order_release);
}

void read_x_then_y()
{
    while(!x.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
    if(y.load(std::memory_order_acquire))    //  ①
        ++z;
}

void read_y_then_x()
{
    while(!y.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
    if(x.load(std::memory_order_acquire))    //  ②
        ++z;
}

int main()
{
    x=false;
    y=false;
    z=0;
    std::thread a(write_x);
    std::thread b(write_y);
    std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
    std::thread d(read_y_then_x);
    a.join();
    b.join();
    c.join();
    d.join();
    assert(z.load()!=0);
}
```

It is said the assert can fire, "Because it's possible for both the load of x② and the load of y① to read false. x and y are written by different threads, so the ordering from the release to acquire in each case has no effect on the operations in the other threads".

I do agree with that acquire-release synchronize nothing, but I don't understand why it could fire. 
Suppose we run read_x_then_y then read_y_then_x. **In order to fire**, in read_x_then_y, x is True, and y should be False; and then we come to read_y_then_x, you have to wait y to become True, and then to check x. But x was already true when y was False. So now, I think x must be True and "++z" would be executed, i.e. , the assert couldn't fire.

Am I wrong? if I am wrong, why x and y could be both false at ① and ②?